# wrong width of img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

i try to build an image uploader for my app. So i need to resize the images.
But often i got the false width value in the img tag.
Not every time. But sometimes when i load the picture 3 times or sometimes if i change the picture then there is the old width in. But also not everytime.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#profil', function () {
    $('#content').height(getRealContentHeight());

    var max_height = getRealContentHeight();
    var max_width = $(window).width();

    var username = getUrlParameter('user');
    var data;
    var x, y, w, h;
    var preview;
    var reader;
    var pic = document.getElementById('pic');


    var jcrop_api;
    $('#upload').bind("change", function () {
        preview = new Image();
        var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];   
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            if (jcrop_api) {
                jcrop_api.setImage(reader.result);
            }

            preview.src = reader.result;

            document.getElementById('pic').src = preview.src;

            alert(pic.height); //there is the false value...sometimes....
            alert(pic.width);
            var size = calculateAspectRatioFit(pic.width, pic.height, max_width, max_height);
            alert("heigth:" + size.height);
            alert("width:" + size.width);
//            document.getElementById('pic').height = size.height;
//            document.getElementById('pic').width = size.width;
            jQuery(function ($) {
                $('#pic').Jcrop({
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    minSize: [50, 50],
                    maxSize: [300, 300],
                    onChange: showCoords,
                    onSelect: showCoords
                }, function () {
                    jcrop_api = this;
                });
            });
            function showCoords(c) {
                x = c.x;
                y = c.y;
                w = c.w;
                h = c.h;
            };
            function calculateAspectRatioFit(srcWidth, srcHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight) {

                var ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);

                return {width: srcWidth * ratio, height: srcHeight * ratio};
            }

        };
        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            preview.src = "";
        }
    });
    $('#continue').bind("click", function () {
       //ajax upload
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the variable and function-scopes. Whit `pic` set in the `pageshow`-function and `pic.width` referring to it in the `change`-function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be one of two issues:

1) Are you setting your '#pic' element's height or width dimensions in css or inline? You may be getting the element's dimensions, not the image's.

2) You are setting 'src' on this img but not waiting until the image has been loaded. You might try:

```
$("#pic").on("load", function() {
    //get dimensions now
});
```

Do you have to display the image at all? Otherwise you can load it in js using:

```
var img = new Image();
```

Then use the jQuery load event handler on this as above. Then set:

```
img.src = 'image url';
```

Comment: yeah...if i use your Function....it triggers 2 or 3 times ^^
i use 
            preview.onload = function () {
                alert(preview.height);
                alert(preview.width);

            };
that works

Comment: Because you're setting src on the same image tag multiple times? So use my javascript suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
$("#pic").height();
$("#pic").width();
$("#pic").outerHeight();
$("#pic").outerWidth();
```

Instead of:

```
pic.height
pic.width
```

And see the right one that suits?